# Scala IDE Error: Main method not found in class 'hello'

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, ide, scala-ide

I am just beginning with my scala development on the Scala IDE(Eclipse). I am trying to create a new project and write a sample hello world program to kick things off. This is my sample program:

```
object hello {
  def main(args: String) = {
    println("Hello World!");
  }
 }
```

I am using Java 8. I don't see any errors in the program. However, when I try to run the program, I get an error like this:

```
Error: Main method not found in class hello, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

I am now clueless. Why is it asking me to create a main function with Java syntax? And why is it throwing an error when there are no problems with the code(As far as I know)? I tried searching for answers on the existing questions but none of them are about scala development.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your main must take an array of string. It currently takes a single string

From scala's official website :

```
object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }
}
```

https://www.scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html

Also, make sure you are using the "run as Scala application" option in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried it but still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using "run as Scala application"?

Comment: Yes, I tried running as a scala application and it is working now. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: I am having the same issue however, it didn't work with any of these options. Eclipse IDE still shows red cross mark on project level but not on any file. I don't know what is wrong. I have tried to def main method like

def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
println("Helo")
}

and

def main(args:Array[String]) {
println("Hello")
}

Answer (score 2):

You have **a class with tha same name in tests**.

Check that your test folder does not contain `object hello.`
Check yuor test package for unique object names.
After renaming, problem must be solved.

There is no difference how to implement `main` method. You can do like this:

```
object hello {
  def main(args: String) = {
    println("Hello World!");
 }
}
```

Or like this:

```
object hello extends App {
    println("Hello World!");
 }
```

```

Comment: You're 1st example won't run. It suffers from the same problem as the original question and can be fixed by following the advice from the accepted answer.

Comment: This actually fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help each and everyone, But I did face the same issue, I cleaned the project and it worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

In my case (Intellij Ultimate 2018.1), I had a test with the same name than the object with the main method:

- `src/main/scala/com/xx/xx/MyApp`
- `src/test/scala/com/xx/xx/MyApp`

when tried to dun main...MyApp failed with the exception in this question.

Just renamed `src/test/scala/com/xx/xx/MyApp` to `MyAppTest`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had both a companion object and a class with the same name, which is normally okay in Scala but appears to have confused Java.

Renaming either the object or class to a different name solved the problem.